# How to generate random data of birth dates using google spreadsheets for a specific years?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a formula to generate random data of birth dates for a specific years (Example: 1995 to 2002) and make it Array like this:

[image]

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Comment: Do note that any date below 1-1-1900 will cause some issue. Do you really need to have dates prior to 1900?

Comment: @JvdV yes, no problem, I will need 1990+, I do not need below 1900. I just gave an example. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try (as I demonstrated in your sheet):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(SEQUENCE(DATE(1992,12,31)-DATE(1900,1,1),1,DATE(1900,1,1)),RANDARRAY(DATE(1992,12,31)-DATE(1900,1,1)),1),COUNTA(A2:A),1)
```

- `SEQUENCE(DATE(1992,12,31)-DATE(1900,1,1),1,DATE(1900,1,1))` - Is used to create an array of valid numeric representations of true dates between 1-1-1900 and 31-12-1992.
- `SORT(<TheAbove>,RANDARRAY(DATE(1992,12,31)-DATE(1900,1,1)),1)` - Is used to sort the array we just created randomly.
- `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(<TheAbove>, COUNTA(A2:A),1)` - Is used to only return as many random birth-dates we need according to other data.

**Note** that this is volatile and will recalculate upon sheet-changes and such. Also note that this is just "slicing" a given array and may fall short when you try to use it on a dataset larger than the given array.

Comment: thank you! But this formula gives me a dates out the range that I want to generate dates in "example: I need just from 1995 to 2002"

Comment: @7amza then change the parts of the formula that determine the years. I went with what you asked for in your original question.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV, I got it! and it's working well thanks for the last edit you made on the sheet that help me to understand how the formula works.

Comment: sorry but I'm facing another issue, when I write the something in Address Column to generate date for that Cell No. 14/D, the previous dates also regenerated! I want to fix the date once it generated and don't change it, any solution for this issue?

Comment: Not if you want true random dates. As I mentioned in my answer this will keep calculating. No way around that without script I recon

Comment: Do you have any script for that? thanks for your follow up with me

Comment: No I don't. You'll have to research that yourself

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help, do you know the script name or any keywords that will help me find it during my research?

Answer (score 5):

That might not be the best approach but it will get you closer to what you want:

```
=DATE(RANDBETWEEN(1995,2002),RANDBETWEEN(1,12),RANDBETWEEN(1,31))
```

There are two issues with this approach:

- you might get a day that does not exist for the particular month. For example, `2/28/2021` exists, but `2/29/2021` does not exist.
- I wasn't able to generate an array but only drag down formulas. When I generate an array, the same random numbers are used and as a result the dates are the same.

For the first issue, you can use `isdate` to check if the random date returned is correct. For example, `2/29/2021` is a wrong date (I hardcopied that date).

[image]

but I guess you can filter out the `FALSE` cases.

I really hope other people can come up with a better approach.

Comment: as @JvdV said in the comment above, the issue causes when we want to random dates below 1-1-1900, but when I use your formula and edit the years range on it: `=DATE(RANDBETWEEN(1995,2002),RANDBETWEEN(1,12),RANDBETWEEN(1,31))`
it doesn't gave me dates out of the range I've choosed.
Now, we just need to make it an array.

Comment: @7amza for me dates 1995-2002 are generated. Maybe you didn't drag down the formulas? But I think JvdV approach will be better

Comment: Yeap, your formula generate dates but I don't want to drag down the formula each time, I need to make it an array. And for the JvdV approach, it's working well but it give me dates out of the years I don't needed, I want to to define a specific years, for example just from 1995 to 2002.

Comment: why the formula generate new date each time I make an edit in the sheet, how to make generate date without it being affected when I make an edit inside the sheet?

Comment: @7amza I think that is one of the restrictions. A "workaround" would be to copy paste the values after the generation of the dates (make sure to change the format to see dates).

Comment: That's what I will work with for now, but I will keep researching for a solution or script as @JvdV said to fix this issue, thank you so much Marios for your help and follow up with me

Comment: @7amza glad it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

As Google Sheets can deal with dates as integers (~ number of days since 1900), choosing a random date between two dates can be a single call to RANDBETWEEN (with the output formatted as Date).

With your initial date written in B1 and your end date in B2, the formula is simply:

```
=RANDBETWEEN($B$1,$B$2)
```

You can paste this formula in as many cells as you want, to generate N different random dates.

Of course, as other answers involving random generators in your sheet, the formula will be recomputed at each change. My suggestion to overcome this would simply be to copy/paste the output, using the "Paste special > Values only" option (right click or "Edit" menu).

Answer (score 0):

#### Script Solution

Just for sake of completeness, here is a solution using a script

#### Initial Considerations

This cannot function like a in sheet function/formula.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

> Custom function arguments must be deterministic. That is, built-in spreadsheet functions that return a different result each time they calculate — such as `NOW()` or `RAND()` — are not allowed as arguments to a custom function. If a custom function tries to return a value based on one of these volatile built-in functions, it will display `Loading...` indefinitely.

> A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead.

So a normal script is needed.

#### The Script

```js
/**
 * Sets the values of a range to random dates.
 */
function generateRandomBdays(range, start, end) {
  let height = range.getHeight();
  let width = range.getWidth();

  let output = [];

  for (let i = 0; i != height; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j != width; j++) {
      row.push(randomBday(start, end));
    }
    output.push(row)
  }
  range.setValues(output);
}

/**
 * Generates a random date beween start and end
 */
function randomBday(start, end) {
  if (start < 2000) start = start - 1900
  start = new Date(`${start}`);

  if (end < 2000) end = end - 1900
  end = new Date(`${end}`);

  let bday = new Date(
    start.getTime() + (Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
    );
  return bday;
}

/**
 * Gets active selection and fills with random dates
 */
function main(){
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getActiveSheet()
  let range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  
  // ============
  generateRandomBdays(range, 1995, 2002); // Change these years to your liking
  // ============
  
}

/**
 * Creates menu when sheet is opened.
 */
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Generate Birthdays')
      .addItem('Generate!', 'main')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Which works like this:

[image]

#### Installation

You will have to copy it into your script editor and then run one of the functions to authorize the script with the permissions it needs. Then next time you open the sheet you should have the menu available.

Alternatively you can delete the `onOpen` function and just use it from the script editor.

Within the `main` function, customize the range of years you need.

#### References

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Overview of Spreadsheet Service in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)